# Where can I find outlet templates for PR2 Plug package?

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to get the pr2_plugs package (allowing PR2 robots to plug themselves into power outlets autonomously) working and tested. I obtained the code from the Github repository listed on the pr2_plugs ROS page (http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_plugs). The launch files (and previous questions on this forum) reference pre-existing outlet template models, which seem to at some point have been provided in the pr2_plugs_actions folder. In particular, I am referring to outlet templates such as green_2x1white, which I assume models a power outlet. However, I have been unable to locate these outlet templates in the various branches of the pr2_plugs repository and anywhere. Would anyone be able to point me toward these files so that I can download them and use them to test the functionality of the pr2_plugs package?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282382/where-can-i-find-outlet-templates-for-pr2-plug-package?/) by [jll](https://answers.ros.org/users/22928/jll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not an authoritative answer (as in: OSRF/ex-Willow Garage ppl should perhaps way in), but after some searching it would appear that the plug template files were never actually really "provided in the pr2_plugs_actions" folder, but downloaded (at build time) by CMake from `pr.willowgarage.com` (see [here](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_plugs/blob/034e164fb5db34bc19006cbb4eab64d66a33a7ef/pr2_plugs_actions/CMakeLists.txt#L30-L31)). This was removed in [79da1f37](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_plugs/commit/79da1f375ddc4afa2f16248b58530ea4ca717285#diff-7dbe80bbff9426b7e3149426c16b913cL62) for some reason (the commit message is unfortunately rather terse and doesn't tell us why: "bugs").

That host doesn't exist any more, but it would seem the files on that host (or at least the ones that you seem interested in) have been moved to `download.ros.org`, specifically to [download.ros.org/data/outlet_detection](http://download.ros.org/data/outlet_detection).

I want to note though, that given the age of the packages and the fact that ROS has progressed (ie: changed) so much since then, I'm not confident things will work out-of-the-box, so even with those files, you'll probably run into problems.

---

Edit: [archielee/pr2_plugs](https://github.com/archielee/pr2_plugs/tree/indigo-devel) appears to be the most recent fork of `pr2_plugs` (at least on github). The last commit message says: "Fully compiles and runs in simulation" (but that was 2 years ago).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-11**:
PR2 maintenance was taken over by Clearpath when WillowGarage shut down. If you have a PR2 you might want to contact them (one of their employees ("TheDash") appears to have done most of the maintenance of `pr2_plugs`).